# How to find via REST if user has chosen to use the default record type for an object or whether to be prompted to choose record type when creating

Tags: rest-api, record-type, user

A user's profile shows which record types are available to that user when creating or editing an object. One of these record types is marked as default. I'm able to get at that info via sobject describe with the user credentials, and then looking at the recordTypeInfos.

But there is a setting in their personal information that says whether or not to use this default record type by default on create, or whether to prompt the user which record type to use. This flag is what I want to look at and I'm confused how to use the REST api to do it. I see that salesforce 1 mobile app must be using this setting because the behavior (prompt or just use default) differs depending on how I have it set. btw, I'm using javascript.
thanks!

Comment: I think it's here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_comobjects_sobject3.htm but no idea how to get there from REST

Comment: thanks for the link, looks like "RecordTypeSelectRequired" flag would be the one. Will look into how to check from REST. thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see how to get at this via REST apis.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for me was to move to winter '14. (v29.0)
The page layouts describe REST endpoint as of that SF version returns a boolean as part of the result: "recordTypeSelectorRequired". If true, then the user should be prompted to choose a record type on create. If false, then the default record type should be used.